# "All rooms" link should open in the same tab

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, chat

When in a chatroom, the **all rooms** button opens in a new tab. This is annoying, as I can always open a link in a new tab but opening one it the same one is harder. Would it be possible to change this?

Comment: I've never understood why browsers offer "Open link in new tab" but not "Open link in current tab"

Comment: I'd rather it be something like a modal dialog rather than a new tab.  I wouldn't want it to replace the chat window though.  Just something that enables easy viewing of all available rooms to switch to, ala *other rooms you're in* fashion.